# making of multilanguage web site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, localization, internationalization

Kindly guide me how to make a site that support 2 languages. On joining the site use will select default language. If user select English all pages, button texts and email should be in English but if user select any other language site for him should be coming in that language. The following areas are language specific.

1. Buttons, Labels, headings and all captions.
2. Email texts and notifications
3. All messages including error messages.

Important thing is that currently I want to make this site in 2 languages but later I may want to convert it to other languages.

Please guide.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585461/how-to-get-the-available-translations-from-a-dll

Comment: @adorablepuppy - they seem mildly similar, but in no way a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basically looking to find out the options for Internationalization & Localization provided by .Net. These typically rely on a combination of language specific resource files & use of the utilities & locale information provided by the System.Globalization namespace. There is a very good step-by-step tutorial which guides you through this process here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/Internationalization_I18N.aspx

The tutorial is aimed at the construction of a desktop application however the vast majority of it's contents are applicable to a website/web-app. There are also some fantastic asp.net specific resources available here:

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/55/internationalization/

Comment: I have not worked before in multi language sites. Can you please guide one thing is it easy to make multi language site from the start or a developed site can be easily converted from single language to multi languaae ?

Comment: Did you read the resources Roja provided?  You have to localized any number you are displaying based on the user's language choice.  Any Labels or messages should be generate their strings based on that choice also.

Comment: It is typically simpler to develop a multi-language site from the very start as you can ensure that you push resources into language specific resource files instead of hard-coding them in. That said migrating a site which doesn't take advantage of resource files shouldn't be all that difficult, mostly it is simply a rather boring process of moving hard-coded resources into resource files and updating code to make use of them through the resources infrastructure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx